# Retain Check Marks with Modal Segue

Tags: objective-c, list, segue, modalviewcontroller, checkmark

I am new to x-code and I was wondering: Is it possible to make check marks retain though you go through a modal segue?

I will check some boxes on my list:

[image]

But when I press done and then come back to the screen with a modal segue it appears as such:

[image]

Is it possible to make these checkmarks stay though I change views modally?

I have this code to create the checkmarks:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.toDoItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListPrototypeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NewItem *toDoItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemName;
    if (toDoItem.completed) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    NewItem *tappedItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pop or dismiss a view controller, that view controller is **gone**. However, you have a few options to remember the state that view controller was in. The easiest way is probably to store a global variable, maybe an `NSArray`, to remember the checked items. Then when you load this view controller, you could "check" any items that exist within that `NSArray`.

Note that this method will only work for the lifetime that the app is open. If they closed the app, it would be gone. If you wanted to maintain the "checked" items for the next time they opened the app, you would need to store it in the `NSUserDefaults` - data in there is available until the app is deleted from the phone.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I'll try to go with NSUserDefaults so the checkmarks are retained when the app is powered up on multiple occasions :)